# Async Concurrent Queue with max concurrency

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm running across a bug with a custom asynchronous queue that calls 10 async functions at a time.

I'm initiating the queue with 50 jobs, once first 10 jobs are finished the queue moves to the subsequent 10 until it finishes all.

The bug I'm coming across is that once it finishes 50, it restarts with first 5 jobs with 2 or 3 or 1 job at a time. It also takes fewer than 10 jobs towards the end of the queue.

Please create these two files and test with mocha and see the output yourself.

**Note**: Set the timeout in mocha to 0 to keep the test running for prolonged period of time.

**Queue.js**

```
function Queue(func, max) {
    this.jobs = [];
    this.func = func;
    this.max = max ? max : 10;
}

Queue.prototype.push = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        self.jobs.push({data: data, resolve: resolve, reject: reject});
        if(!self.progress) {
            self.progress = true;
            self.run();
        }
    });
};

Queue.prototype.run = function() {
    var self = this;
    var tasks = [];

    console.log("--------------------");

    for(var i=0; i<this.jobs.length && i < this.max; i++) {
        tasks.push(this.jobs.shift());
        console.log("queuing", tasks[tasks.length-1].data);
    }
    console.log("Total jobs queued", tasks.length);

    Promise.all(
        tasks.map(function(task){
            return self.func(task.data)
                .then(task.resolve, task.reject);
        }
    )).then(this.next.bind(this));
};

Queue.prototype.next = function(){
    if(this.jobs.length) {
        this.run();
    } else {
        this.progress = false;
    }
};

module.exports = Queue;
```

**QueueTest.js**

```
function async(data) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("resolving", data);
            resolve(data);
        }, Math.random() * 5000);
    });
}

it("should test queue", function(done){
    var queue = new Queue(async);
    Promise.all(
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
            30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50].map(queue.push.bind(queue))
    ).then(function(){
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried removing jobs from the queue, once the job is done, and then keep checking if queue not empty? typical queue. Or once the job is done, remove from original queue, and move it to jobDoneQueue.

Comment: this line `tasks.push(this.jobs.shift());` in the run function basically does that, tasks is the local variable within the run function and exists only within the scope and has enqueued jobs. shift removes them from the main queue.

Comment: @NalinAgrawal, can you please run and test this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the `for` loop in `Queue.prototype.run`.

I can't immediately see why it should misbehave the way it does but a fix is to replace the `for` loop with `self.jobs.splice()` to create the `tasks` array.

```
Queue.prototype.run = function() {
    console.log("--------------------");
    var self = this;
    var tasks = self.jobs.splice(0, self.max); // <<<<<<<< this is the fix
    console.log("tasks:", tasks.map(obj => obj.data));

    Promise.all(
        tasks.map(function(task){
            return self.func(task.data)
            .then(task.resolve, task.reject);
        }
    )).then(this.next.bind(this));
};
```

Nothing else needs to change.

Comment: wow, nice. at least we can conclude that problem is somehow because of the `for` loop and `splice` did solve the problem. By the way `this` and `self` both works. I couldn't wrap my head around that how `for` loop can be a culprit.

Comment: I don't know either. I just got lucky in that `splice` was the first thing I tried.

Comment: Whatever the issue was, it's a straightforward synchronous thing. My fix doesn't change anything to do with promises or then()ing.

Comment: lol, I'm thinking maybe somehow a closure is happening and is reading a dirty length value of the jobs array as values are getting provided (values are coming concurrently by Promise.all in the QueueTest class) it's just a speculation to provide some food for thought :)

Comment: It's to do with `this.jobs` changing length as the loop iterates. Try assigning `var n = this.jobs.length;` before the loop and constructing the loop with `for(var i=0; i<n && i < this.max; i++)`. That should fix it too.

Comment: Anyways, `splice()` is the daddy. I wouldn't mess around with a `for` loop.

Comment: Oh great discovery and the root of the problem. and i remember something, never to iterate the array while you are deleting items from it, classic problem :))))

Comment: Thanks for the help. on the side note, if you notice this Queue is eager, as soon as the first job comes in, it goes ahead with the run if the queue is not in progress and any subsequent jobs get pushed in the background and on the next turn it takes 10 jobs, can you please advise for a better strategy?

Comment: within the `push` method, I updated to this `setTimeout(self.run.bind(self), 0)`, now it's starting 10 jobs to begin with instead of `self.run()`. Thanks again for all the help

Comment: I noticed that job 0 gets serviced on its own and thought it was a rather good feature. It's not so much that the queue itself is eager but that `run()` is eager to service the queue. It's rather like a queue at a supermarket, where the checkout assistant starts to service the queue as soon as someone arrives. (The analogy falls apart after that because supermarket checkouts don't work in batches of 10 customers).

Comment: yes that's correct that run was eager but I always felt like a bottleneck because this remote service takes like a minute or less to finish the work (uploading files etc.) and i always felt not so efficient waiting for a minute until it picks the full throttle in the next iteration. While the remote service can take concurrent load, but not so many simultaneous, it failed i think with 15 or 20 concurrent requests, so I picked max as 10. I'm happy it's gold now :)

Comment: I see your point. Have you looked at Bluebird's  `.each()` with concurrency option? It's even less bottleneky in that it maintains a pool of in-flight async tasks up to a maximum number rather than batching *per se*. However, it's not equipped to accept new items to be serviced after servicing commences. But maybe you could adopt the same concept of "one out, one in".

Comment: I looked it up just now, although I prefer to keep code vanilla while depending only on native api, but would like to see a line of code on how would I modify my test in QueueTest.js to use blubird .each with my async example function.

Comment: With Bluebird, it's `Promise.map()` with concurrency option, not `Promise.each()` - sorry, my bad. So with `Promise.map()` you would write `Promise.map([0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 50], async, {concurrency:10}).then(function() {
 console.log('... Done');
});` -  with no need for `Queue()`. However, it's not the same thing as your `Queue()`, which allows further data elements to be push()ed after the queue starts to run. If that's an important feature, and you want Bluebird like concurrency, then adapt the `.run()` method to keep a pool of in-flight promises topped up as each earlier promise settles.

Comment: I gave it a try and found that the "pool" needs be nothing more than an integer, and the need for `Promise.all()` in `Queue.prototype.run()` disappeared.

Comment: sorry i didn't get your last comment about `Queue.prototype.run`

Comment: In `Queue.prototype.run()`, the need for `Promise.all()` disappeared ... it's just a hint for you, when you come to code a concurrency pool for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this condition in the `for` loop: `i<this.jobs.length`

`i` is counting the number of jobs scheduled in the batch.  This condition is correct when `i` is an index in the jobs array.  In this case, we just want to confirm there are still jobs left to process, so we can simply use: `this.jobs.length>0`

The odd behavior towards the end of the queue is because the length is falling as elements are shifted off the jobs array, but the number of jobs scheduled in that batch (`i`) is increasing.  Let's take an example where `this.jobs.length` is 4 when entering the for loop:

| i | this.jobs.length | i < this.jobs.length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4 | true |
| 1 | 3 | true |
| 2 | 2 | false |

In this case, the loop is exited after only scheduling 2 of the four jobs in the queue.  Checking if there are remaining tasks instead fixes the issue:

```js
for(var i=0; this.jobs.length > 0 && i < this.max; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Schedule task parallelly from array without waiting any to finish within allowed threads

```
const fastQueue = async <T, Q>(
  x: T[],
  threads: number,
  fn: (v: T, i: number, a: T[]) => Promise<Q>
) => {
  let k = 0;
  const result = Array(x.length) as Q[];
  await Promise.all(
    [...Array(threads)].map(async () => {
      while (k < x.length) result[k] = await fn(x[k], k++, x);
    })
  );
  return result;
};

const demo = async () => {
    const wait = (x: number) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, x, x))
    console.time('a')
    console.log(await fastQueue([1000, 2000, 3000, 2000, 2000], 4, (v) => wait(v)))
    console.timeEnd('a')
}
demo();
```