# JS async / await tasks queue

Tags: javascript, async-await

In my JS app I'm using the async / await feature. I would like to perform multiple API calls and would like them to be fired one after other. In other words I would like to replace this simple method:

```
const addTask = async (url, options) => {
    return await fetch(url, options)
}
```

with something more complex.. like:

```
let tasksQueue = []
const addTask = async (url, options) => {
    tasksQueue.push({url, options})
    ...// perform fetch in queue
    return await ...
}
```

What will be the best way to handle the asynchronous returns?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705043/async-queue-with-async-await-style-functions, this might get you started. Cool question tho

Comment: what do you expect to get if one of the requests fails?

Comment: Also: https://medium.com/@griffinmichl/asynchronous-javascript-queue-920828f6327

Comment: @skyboyer I would like the next task to be fired

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could save previous pending promise, await for it before calling next `fetch`.

```js
// fake fetch for demo purposes only
const fetch = (url, options) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, {url, options}))

// task executor
const addTask = (() => {
  let pending = Promise.resolve();
  
  const run = async (url, options) => {
    try {
      await pending;
    } finally {
      return fetch(url, options);
    }
  }

  // update pending promise so that next task could await for it
  return (url, options) => (pending = run(url, options))
})();

addTask('url1', {options: 1}).then(console.log)

addTask('url2', {options: 2}).then(console.log)

addTask('url3', {options: 3}).then(console.log)
```

Comment: Nice answer! One issue: If one of the requests fail, the OP would like the next task to be fired, yet `finally` doesn't catch errors. I think you need `catch(e) {}` ahead of it.

Comment: @jib The next request would always run because `finally` block runs even if an exception occurs http://jsfiddle.net/xmd5rp7g/ Also it is generally bad idea  to swallow exceptions. :)

Comment: Interesting! Returning inside a `finally` statement apparently swallows any error from that `try` block. Compare to http://jsfiddle.net/xmd5rp7g/12/ where a catch (commented out) is needed for the same result. That's because `await pending` creates a promise-*branch* with its own error propagation, separate from the branch returned to the caller of `addTask`. TIL.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko This is nice and works well. My only concern is eslint isn't happy with the `finally .. return ...`
Ref: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unsafe-finally
Any thoughts?

Comment: @nevf Depending on what you want, you could do this: `try { await pending } catch(e) { console.error(e) }; return fetch(url, options);`

Comment: Thanks @YuryTarabanko Just create a npm package, added context and support named fn

https://github.com/baryon/named-promise-task

Answer (score 108):

You could use a [Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)#Examples) data structure as your base and add special behavior in a child class. a `Queue` has a well known interface of two methods `enqueue()` (**add** new item to end) and `dequeue()` (**remove** first item). In your case `dequeue()` awaits for the async task.

Special behavior:

> 1. Each time a new task (e.g. `fetch('url')`) gets **enqueued**, `this.dequeue()` gets invoked.
> 2. What  `dequeue()` does:
>
>    1. if queue is empty ➜ `return false` (break out of recursion)
>    2. if queue is busy ➜ `return false` (prev. task not finished)
>    3. else ➜ remove **first** task from queue and run it
>    4. on task "complete" (successful or with errors) ➜ recursive call `dequeue()` (2.), until queue is empty..

```js
class Queue {
  constructor() { this._items = []; }
  enqueue(item) { this._items.push(item); }
  dequeue()     { return this._items.shift(); }
  get size()    { return this._items.length; }
}

class AutoQueue extends Queue {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._pendingPromise = false;
  }

  enqueue(action) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      super.enqueue({ action, resolve, reject });
      this.dequeue();
    });
  }

  async dequeue() {
    if (this._pendingPromise) return false;

    let item = super.dequeue();

    if (!item) return false;

    try {
      this._pendingPromise = true;

      let payload = await item.action(this);

      this._pendingPromise = false;
      item.resolve(payload);
    } catch (e) {
      this._pendingPromise = false;
      item.reject(e);
    } finally {
      this.dequeue();
    }

    return true;
  }
}

// Helper function for 'fake' tasks
// Returned Promise is wrapped! (tasks should not run right after initialization)
let _ = ({ ms, ...foo } = {}) => () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms, foo));
// ... create some fake tasks
let p1 = _({ ms: 50, url: '❪❫', data: { w: 1 } });
let p2 = _({ ms: 20, url: '❪❫', data: { x: 2 } });
let p3 = _({ ms: 70, url: '❪❫', data: { y: 3 } });
let p4 = _({ ms: 30, url: '❪❫', data: { z: 4 } });

const aQueue = new AutoQueue();
const start = performance.now();

aQueue.enqueue(p1).then(({ url, data }) => console.log('%s DONE %fms', url, performance.now() - start)); //          = 50
aQueue.enqueue(p2).then(({ url, data }) => console.log('%s DONE %fms', url, performance.now() - start)); // 50 + 20  = 70
aQueue.enqueue(p3).then(({ url, data }) => console.log('%s DONE %fms', url, performance.now() - start)); // 70 + 70  = 140
aQueue.enqueue(p4).then(({ url, data }) => console.log('%s DONE %fms', url, performance.now() - start)); // 140 + 30 = 170
```

#### Interactive demo:

Full code demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/async-queue-ghpqm?file=/src/index.js
You can play around and watch results in console and/or dev-tools "performance" tab. The rest of this answer is based on it.

#### Explain:

`enqueue()` returns a **new** `Promise`, that will be **resolved**(or rejected) *at some point later*. This `Promise` can be used to handle the response of your `async` task Fn.

`enqueue()` actually `push()` an `Object` into the queue, that *holds* the task Fn and the *control methods* for the returned Promise.

Since the *unwrapped* returned `Promise` insta. starts to run, `this.dequeue()` is invoked each time we enqueue a new task.

With some [performance.measure()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/measure) added to our `task`, we get good visualization of our queue:

[image] (*.gif animation)

- **1st row** is our queue instance
- New enqueued `tasks` have a "❚❚ waiting.." period (**3nd row**) (might be `< 1ms` if queue is empty`)
- At some point it is dequeued and "▶ runs.." for a while (**2nd row**)

Log output ([console.table()](http://console.table)):

[image: console.table() for prev. example]

> Explain:
> 1st `task` is `enqueue()`d at `2.58ms` right after queue initialization.
> Since our queue is empty there is like no `❚❚ waiting` (`0.04ms`➜ ~`40μm`).
> Task runtime `13.88ms` ➜ dequeue

---

### Class `Queue` is *just a wrapper* for native `Array` Fn´s!

You can of course implement this in one class. I just want to show, that you can build what you want from already known data structures. There are some good reasons for not using an `Array`:

- A `Queue` data-structure is defined by an **Interface** of two public methods. Using an `Array` might tempt others to use native `Array` methods on it like `.reverse()`,.. which would break the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)#Examples).
- `enqueue()` and `dequeue()` are much more readable than `push()` and `shift()`
- If you already have an out-implemented `Queue` class, you can extend from it (re-usable code)
- You can replace the item `Array` in `class Queue` by an other data structure: A "[Doubly Linked List](https://adrianmejia.com/data-structures-time-complexity-for-beginners-arrays-hashmaps-linked-lists-stacks-queues-tutorial/#Queue-implemented-with-a-Doubly-Linked-List)" which would reduce **code complexity** for `Array.shift()` from O(n) [linear] to O(1) [constant]. (➜ better time complexity than native array Fn!) (➜ final demo)

---

### Code limitations

This `AutoQueue` class is not limited to `async` functions. It handles *anything*, that can be called like `await item[MyTask](this)`:

1. `let task = queue => {..}` ➜ ***sync*** functions
2. `let task = async queue => {..}` ➜ **async** functions
3. `let task = queue => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100)` ➜ `new Promise()`

> Note: We already call our tasks with `await`, where `await` **wraps** the response of the task into a `Promise`.
> Nr 2. (**async** function), always returns a `Promise` on its own, and the `await` call just wraps a `Promise` into an other `Promise`, which is slightly less efficient.
> Nr 3. is fine. Returned Promises will **not** get wrapped by `await`

This is how async functions are executed: ([source](https://exploringjs.com/es2016-es2017/ch_async-functions.html#_async-functions-are-started-synchronously-settled-asynchronously))

1. The result of an async function is always a Promise `p`. That Promise is created when starting the execution of the async function.
2. The body is executed. Execution may finish permanently via return or throw. Or it may finish temporarily via await; in which case execution will usually continue later on.
3. The Promise `p` is returned.

The following code demonstrates how that works:

```
async function asyncFunc() {
    console.log('asyncFunc()'); // (A)
    return 'abc';
}
asyncFunc().
    then(x => console.log(`Resolved: ${x}`)); // (B)
console.log('main'); // (C)

// Output:
// asyncFunc()
// main
// Resolved: abc
```

You can rely on the following order:

1. Line (A): the async function is started synchronously. The async function’s Promise is resolved via return.
2. Line (C): execution continues.
3. Line (B): Notification of Promise resolution happens asynchronously.

Read more: "[Callable values](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_callables.html)"
Read more: "[Async functions](https://exploringjs.com/es2016-es2017/ch_async-functions.html)"

---

### Performance limitations

Since `AutoQueue` is limited to handle **one** task **after the other**, it might become a bottleneck in our app. Limiting factors are:

1. **Tasks per time:** ➜ Frequency of new `enqueue()`d tasks.
2. **Runtime per task** ➜ Blocking time in `dequeue()` until task complete

#### 1. Tasks per time

This is our responsibility! We can get the current size of the `queue` at any time: `size = queue.size`. Your *outer* script needs a "fail-over" case for a steadily growing queue (check "Stacked `wait` times" section).

You want to avoid a "queue overflow" like this, where average/mean `waitTime` increases over time.

```
+-------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| tasks | enqueueMin(ms) | enqueueMax(ms) | runtimeMin(ms) | runtimeMax(ms) |
| 20    |              0 |            200 |             10 |             30 |
+-------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

[image]

[image]

- ➜ Task `20/20` waits for `195ms` until exec starts
- ➜ From the time, our last task was randomly enqueued, it takes another **+ ~232ms**, until all tasks were resolved.

#### 2. Runtime per task

This one is harder to deal with. (Waiting for a `fetch()` can not be improved and we need to wait until the HTTP request completed).
Maybe your `fetch()` tasks rely on each others response and a long runtime will block the others.

But there are some things we could do:

- Maybe we could cache responses ➜ Reduce runtime on next enqueue.
- Maybe we `fetch()` from a CDN and have an alternative URI we could use. In this case we can return a `new Promise` from our `task` that will be run before the next `task` is `enqueue()`d. (see "Error handling"):

  ```
  queue.enqueue(queue => Promise.race(fetch('url1'), fetch('url2')));
  ```
- Maybe your have some kind of "[long polling](https://javascript.info/long-polling)" or periodic ajax `task` that runs every x seconds thatcan not be cached. Even if you can not reduce the runtime itself, you could record the runtimes which would give you an aprox. estimation of the next run. Maybe can swap long running tasks to other queue instances.

---

### Balanced `AutoQueue`

What is an "efficient" `Queue`? - Your first thought might be something like:

> The most efficient `Queue` handles most `tasks` in shortest period of time?

Since we can not improve our `task` runtime, can we **lower the waiting** time? The example is a `queue` with *zero* (`~0ms`) waiting time between tasks.

> Hint: In order to compare our next examples we need some *base* stats that will not change:

```
+-------+----------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+
| count |  random fake runtime for tasks  |  random enqueue() offset for tasks  |
+-------+----------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+
| tasks | runtimeMin(ms) | runtimeMax(ms) | msEnqueueMin(ms) | msEnqueueMax(ms) |
| 200   |             10 |             30 |                0 |             4000 |
+-------+----------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+
     Avg. task runtime: ⇒ (10ms + 30ms) / 2   = 20ms
     Total time:        ⇒  20ms * 200         = 4000ms ≙ 4s
  ➜ We expect our queue to be resolved after ~4s
  ➜ For consistent enqueue() frequency we set msEnqueueMax to 4000
```

[image]

- `AutoQueue` finished last `dequeue()` after `~4.12s` (^^ see tooltip).
- Which is `~120ms` longer than our expected `4s`:

  > Hint: There is a small "Log" block" after each task `~0.3ms`, where I build/push an `Object` with log marks to a global 'Array' for the `console.table()` log at the end. This explains `200 * 0.3ms = 60ms`.. The missing `60ms`are untracked (you see the small gap between the tasks) -> `0.3ms`/task for our test loop and probably some delay from open Dev-Tools,..

We come back to these timings later.

The initialization code for our `queue`:

```
const queue = new AutoQueue();
// .. get 200 random Int numbers for our task "fake" runtimes [10-30]ms
let runtimes = Array.from({ length: 200 }, () => rndInt(10, 30));
let i = 0;
let enqueue = queue => {
    if (i >= 200) {
        return queue; // break out condition
    }
    i++;
    queue
        .enqueue(
            newTask({ // generate a "fake" task with of a rand. runtime
                ms: runtimes[i - 1],
                url: _(i)
            })
        )
        .then(payload => {
            enqueue(queue);
        });
};
enqueue(queue); // start recurion
```

We recursively `enqueue()` our next task, right after the previous finished. You might have noticed the **analogy** to a *typical* `Promise.then()` chain, right?

> Hint: We don´t need a `Queue` if we already *know* the order and total number of `tasks`  to run in sequence. We can use a `Promise` chain and get the same results.

Sometimes we don´t know all next steps right at the start of our script..

..You might need more **flexibility**, and the *next* task we want to run depends on the response of the previous `task`. - Maybe your app relies on a REST API (multiple endpoints), and you are limited to max X simultaneous API request(s). We can not spam the API with requests from all over your app. You even don´t know when the next request gets `enqueue()`d (e.g. API requests are triggered by `click()` events?..

Ok, for the next example I changed the initialization code a bit:

We now enqueue 200 tasks **randomly** within [0-4000ms] period. - To be fair, we reduced the range by `30ms` (max task runtime) to [0-3970ms]. Now our **randomly filled** queue has a chance to keep inside `4000ms` *limit*.

[image]
[image]
[image]

What we can get out or the Dev-Tools performance login:

- Random `enqueue()` leads to a big number of "waiting" tasks.

  > Makes sense, since we enqueued all tasks within first `~4000ms`, they must overlap somehow. Checking the table output we can verify: Max `queue.size` is `22` at the time task `170/200`was enqueued.
- Waiting tasks are not evenly distributed. Right after start there are even some **idle** section.

  > Because of the random `enqueue()` it it unlikely to get a `0ms` offset for our first task.
  > `~20ms` runtime for each task lead to the **stacking** effect over time.
- We can sort tasks by "wait ms" (see screen): Longest waiting time was `>400ms`.

  > There might be a relation between `queue.size` (column: `sizeOnAdd`) and `wait ms` (see next section).
- Our `AwaitQueue` completed last `dequeue()` `~4.37s` after its initialization (check tooltip in "performance" tab). An average runtime of `20,786ms / task` (expected: `20ms`) gives us a **total runtime** of `4157.13ms` (expected: `4000ms` ≙ `4s`).

  > We still have our "Log" blocks and the exec. time of our test script it self  `~120ms`. Still `~37ms` longer? Summing up all idle "gaps" right at the start explains the missing `~37ms`

#### Back to our initial "definition"

> The most efficient `Queue` handles most `tasks` in shortest period of time?

**Assumption:** Apart from the random offset, `tasks` get `enqueue()`d in the previous example, **both** queues handled the **same number** of `task`s (**equal avg. runtime**) within the **same period of time**. Neither the **waiting** time of an enqueued `task` nor the `queue.size` affect the total runtime. Both have the same efficiency?

Since a `Queue`, by its nature, shrinks our coding possibilities it is best not to use a `Queue` if we talk about efficient code (tasks per time).

A queue helps us to *straighten* tasks in an async environment into a sync pattern. That is exactly what we want. ➜ "Run an *unknown* sequence of tasks in **a row**".

If you find yourself asking things like: "If a new `task` gets enqueued into an already *filled* queue, the time we have to **wait** for our result, is increased by the run times of the others. That´s less efficient!".
Then you are doing it wrong:

- You either enqueue tasks that have no dependency (in some way) on each other (logical oder programmatical dependency) or there is a dependency which would not increase the total runtime of our script. - We have to wait for the others anyway.

---

### Stacked `wait` times

We have see a peak `wait` time of `461.05ms` for a task before it runs. Wouldn't it be great if we could forecast the `wait` time for a task before we decide to enqueue it?

At first we analyse the behavior of our `AutoQueue` class over longer times.
(re-post screens)

[image]
[image]

We can build a chart from from what `console.table()` output:

[image]

Beside the `wait` time of a `task`, we can see the random [10-30ms] `runtime` and 3 curves, representing the current `queue.size`, recorded at the time a `task` ..

- .. is `enqueued()`
- .. starts to run. (`dequeue()`)
- .. the task finished (right before the next `dequeue()`)

2 more runs for comparison (similar trend):

- chart run 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGB3K.png
- chart run 3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaQ39.png

#### Can we find dependencies among each other?

If we could find a relation between any of those recorded chart lines, it might help us to understand how a `queue` behaves over time (➜ constantly filled up with new tasks).

> Exkurs: What is a relation?
> We are looking for an equation that **projects** the `wait ms` curve **onto** one of the 3 `queue.size` records. **This would proof a direct dependency between both.**

For our last run, we changed our start parameters:

- Task count:   `200`    ➜ `1000`    (5x)
- msEnqueueMax: `4000ms` ➜ `20000ms` (5x)

  ```
  +-------+----------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+
  | count |  random fake runtime for tasks  |  random enqueue() offset for tasks  |
  +-------+----------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+
  | tasks | runtimeMin(ms) | runtimeMax(ms) | msEnqueueMin(ms) | msEnqueueMax(ms) |
  | 1000  |             10 |             30 |                0 |            20000 |
  +-------+----------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+
       Avg. task runtime: ⇒ (10ms + 30ms) / 2   = 20ms (like before)
       Total time:        ⇒  20ms * 1000        = 20000ms ≙ 20s
    ➜ We expect our queue to be resolved after ~20s 
    ➜ For consistent enqueue() frequency we set msEnqueueMax to 20000
  ```

[image]
(interactive chart: https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/p4ZYx/2/)

We see the same trend. `wait ms` increases over time (nothing new). Since our 3 `queue.size` lines at the bottom were drawn into the same chart (Y-axis has `ms` scale), they are barely visible. Quick switch to a logarithmic scale for better comparison:

[image]
(interactive chart: https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/lZngg/1/)

The two dotted lines for `queue.size [on start]` and `queue.size [on end]` pretty much overlap each other and fall down to "0" once our queue gets empty, at the end.

`queue.size [on add]` looks very similar to the `wait ms` line. That is what we need.

```
   {queue.size [on add]} * X = {wait ms}
⇔ X = {wait ms} / {queue.size [on add]}
```

This alone does not help us at runtime because `wait ms` is unknown for a new enqueued task (has not yet been run). So we still have 2 unknown variable: `X` and `wait ms`. We need an other relation that helps us.

First of all, we print our new ration `{wait ms} / {queue.size [on add]}` into the chart (light green), and its mean/average (light green horizontal dashed). This is pretty close to `20ms` (avg. `run ms` of our tasks), right?

Switch back to `linear` Y-axes and set its "max scale" to `80ms` to get a better view of it. (hint: `wait ms` is now beyond the view port)

[image]
(interactive chart: https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/Tknnr/4/)

Back to the random runtimes of our tasks (dot cloud). We still have our "total mean" of `20.72ms` (dark green dashed horizontal). We can also calc the mean of our previous tasks **at runtime** (e.g. task 370 gets enqueued ➜ What is the current mean runtime for task [1,.., 269] = mean runtime). But we could even be more precise:

The more tasks we enqueue the less impact they have on total  "mean runtime". So let´s just calc the "mean runtime" of the **last** e.g. 50 `tasks`. Which leads to a **consistent impact** of 1/50 per task for the "mean runtime". ➜ Peak runtimes get straighten and the trend (up/down) is taken into account. (dark green horizontal path curve next to the light green from our 1. equation).

Things we can do now:

1. We can **eliminate** `X` from our 1st equation (light green). ➜ `X` can be expressed by the "mean runtimes of previous `n` e.g. 50 tasks (dark green).
   Our new equation just depends on variables, that are known at runtime, right at the point of enqueue:

   ```
   // mean runtime from prev. n tasks:
   X = {[taskRun[-50], .. , taskRun[-2], taskRun[-1] ] / n } ms

   // .. replace X in 1st equation:
   ⇒ {wait ms} = {queue.size [on add]} * {[runtime[-50], .. , runtime[-2], runtime[-1] ] / n } ms
   ```
2. We can draw a new diagram curve to our chart and check how close it is compared to the recorded `wait ms` (orange)

[image]
(interactive chart: https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/LFp1d/2/)

#### Conclusion

We can forecast the `wait` for a task before it gets enqueued, given the fact the run times of our tasks can be determined somehow. So it works best in situations where you enqueue tasks of the same type/function:
Use case: An `AutoQueue` instance is filled up with render tasks for your UI components. Render time might not change chat much (compared to `fetch()`). Maybe you render 1000 location marks on a map. Each mark is an instance of a class with a `render()` Fn.

---

### Tips

1. `Queues` are used for various tasks. ➜ Implement dedicated `Queue` class variations for different kinds of logic (not mix different logic in one class)
2. Check all `task`s that **might** be enqueued to the same `AutoQueue` instance (now or in future), they could be blocked by **all the others**.
3. An `AutoQueue` will not improve the runtime, at best it will not get lowered.
4. Use different `AutoQueue` instances for different `Task` types.
5. Monitor the size of your `AutoQueue`, particular ..

   - .. on heavy usage (high frequently of `enqueue()`)
   - .. on *long* or *unknown* `task` runtimes
6. Check your error handling. Since errors inside your `tasks` will just `reject` their returned promise on enqueue (`promise = queue.enqueue(..)`) and will not stop the dequeue process. You can handle errors..

   - .. inside your tasks ➜ `try{..} catch(e){ .. }
   - .. right after it (before the next) ➜ `return new Promise()`
   - .. "async" ➜ `queue.enqueue(..).catch(e => {..})`
   - .. "global" ➜ error handler inside the `AutoQueue` class
7. Depending on the implementation of your `Queue` you might watch the `queue.size`. An `Array`, filled up with 1000 tasks, is less effective than a decentralized data-structure like the "Doubly Linked List" I used in the final code.
8. Avoid recursion hell. (It is OK to use `tasks` that `enqueue()` others) - But, it is no fun to debug an `AutoQueue` where `tasks` are dynamically `enqueue()`e by others in an `async` environment..
9. At first glance a `Queue` might solve a *problem* (at a certain level of abstraction). However, in most cases it shrinks existing flexibility. It adds an additional "control layer" to our code (which in most cases, is what we want) at the same time, we sign a contract to accept the strict rules of a `Queue`. Even if it solves a problem, it might not be the best solution.

---

### Add more features [basic]

- **Stop "Auto `dequeue()`" on `enqueue()`:**
  Since our `AutoQueue` class is generic and not limited to *long running* HTTP requests(), you can `enqueue()` any function that has to run in sequence, even `3min` running functions for e.g. "store updates for modules",.. You can not guarantee, that when you `enqueue()` 100 tasks in a loop, the prev added task is not already `dequeued()`.

  > You might want to prevent `enqueue()` from calling `dequeue()` until all where added.

  ```
  enqueue(action, autoDequeue = true) { // new
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          super.enqueue({ action, resolve, reject });
          if (autoDequeue) this.dequeue(); // new
      });
  }
  ```

  .. and then call `queue.dequeue()` manually at some point.
- **Control methods:** `stop` / `pause` / `start`
  You can add more control methods. Maybe your app has multiple modules that all try to `fetch()` there resources on pageload. An `AutoQueue()` works like a `Controller`. You can monitor how many tasks are "waiting.." and add more controls:

  ```
  class AutoQueue extends Queue {
      constructor() {
          this._stop = false;  // new
          this._pause = false; // new
      }

      enqueue(action) { .. }

      async dequeue() {
          if (this._pendingPromise) return false;
          if (this._pause ) return false; // new

          if (this._stop) { // new
              this._queue = [];
              this._stop = false;
              return false;
          }

          let item = super.dequeue();
          ..
      }

      stop() { // new
          this._stop = true;
      }

      pause() { // new
          this._pause = true;
      }

      start() { // new
          this._stop = false;
          this._pause = false;
          return await this.dequeue();
      }
  }
  ```
- **Forward response:**
  You might want to process the "response/value" of a `task` in the **next** task. It is not guaranteed that our **prev.** task has not already finished, at the time we enqueue the **2nd** task.
  Therefore it might be best to store the response of the prev. task inside the class and forward it to the next: `this._payload = await item.action(this._payload)`

---

### Error handling

Thrown errors inside a `task` Fn reject the promise returned by `enqueue()` and will not stop the dequeue process. You might want to handle error before next `task` starts to run:

```
queue.enqueue(queue => myTask() ).catch({ .. }); // async error handling

queue.enqueue(queue  =>
    myTask()
        .then(payload=> otherTask(payload)) // .. inner task
        .catch(() => { .. }) // sync error handling
);
```

Since our `Queue` is *dump*, and just `await`´s for our task´s to be resolved (`item.action(this)`), no one prevents you from **returning**  a `new Promise()` from the current running `task` Fn. - It will be resolved before the next task gets dequeued.

You can `throw new Error()` inside task Fn´s and handle them "outside"/after run:`queue.enqueue(..).catch()`.
You can easily add a custom Error handling inside the `dequeue()` method that calls `this.stop()` to clear "*on hold*"(enqueued) tasks..

You can even manipulate the queue from inside your task functions. Check: `await item.action(this)` invokes with `this` and gives access to the `Queue` instance. (this is optional). There are use cases where `task` Fn´s should not be able to.

---

### Add more features [advanced]

... text limt reached :D

more: https://gist.github.com/exodus4d/6f02ed518c5a5494808366291ff1e206

---

### Read more

- Blog: "[Asynchronous Recursion with Callbacks, Promises and Async](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2017/09/14/asynchronous-recursion.html)"
- Book: "[Callable values](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_callables.html)"
- Book: "[Async functions](https://exploringjs.com/es2016-es2017/ch_async-functions.html)"

Comment: This has to be the most thorough answer I've seen on SO

Comment: Very solid answer. I replicated your thoughts here as prototypical implementation and currently testing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one I made earlier, [also available in typescript](https://gist.github.com/mfbx9da4/406145db83c4142720754bdab1e2f125)

```js
function createAsyncQueue(opts = { dedupe: false }) {
  const { dedupe } = opts
  let queue = []
  let running
  const push = task => {
    if (dedupe) queue = []
    queue.push(task)
    if (!running) running = start()
    return running.finally(() => {
      running = undefined
    })
  }
  const start = async () => {
    const res = []
    while (queue.length) {
      const item = queue.shift()
      res.push(await item())
    }
    return res
  }
  return { push, queue, flush: () => running || Promise.resolve([]) }
}





// -----  tests below 





const sleep = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

async function test1() {
  const myQueue = createAsyncQueue()
  myQueue.push(async () => {
    console.log(100)
    await sleep(100)
    return 100
  })
  myQueue.push(async () => {
    console.log(10)
    await sleep(10)
    return 10
  })
  console.log(await myQueue.flush())
}

async function test2() {
  const myQueue = createAsyncQueue({ dedupe: true })
  myQueue.push(async () => {
    console.log(100)
    await sleep(100)
    return 100
  })
  myQueue.push(async () => {
    console.log(10)
    await sleep(10)
    return 10
  })
  myQueue.push(async () => {
    console.log(9)
    await sleep(9)
    return 9
  })
  // only 100 and 9 will be executed
  // concurrent executions will be deduped
  console.log(await myQueue.flush())
}
test1().then(test2)
```

Example usage:

```
const queue = createAsyncQueue()
const task1 = async () => {
  await fetchItem()
}
queue.push(task1)
const task2 = async () => {
  await fetchItem()
}
queue.push(task2)
// task1 will be guaranteed to be executed before task2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think there is a simple solution like follows.

```js
class AsyncQueue {
    constructor() {
        this.promise = Promise.resolve()
    }

    push = (task) => {
        this.promise = this.promise.then(task)
    }
}

let count = 0

let dummy = () =>
    new Promise((res) => {
        const ms = 400 + Math.ceil(1200 * Math.random())
        console.log('will wait', ms, 'ms')
        setTimeout(res, ms)
    })

const foo = async (args) => {
    const s = ++count
    console.log('start foo', s)
    await dummy()
    console.log('end foo', s)
}

console.log('begin')

const q = new AsyncQueue()

q.push(foo)
q.push(foo)
q.push(foo)
q.push(foo)

console.log('end')
```

For your case you can do something like this:

```js
const q = new AsyncQueue()
const addTask = (url, options) => {
    q.push(() => fetch(url, options))
}
```

If you want to handle some results:

```js
const q = new AsyncQueue()
const addTask = (url, options, handleResults) => {
    q.push(async () => handleResults(await fetch(url, options)))
}
```

Not sure about performance, I just think it is a quick clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71239408/8784402

#### Schedule task parallelly from array without waiting any to finish within allowed threads

```
const fastQueue = async <T, Q>(
  x: T[],
  threads: number,
  fn: (v: T, i: number, a: T[]) => Promise<Q>
) => {
  let k = 0;
  const result = Array(x.length) as Q[];
  await Promise.all(
    [...Array(threads)].map(async () => {
      while (k < x.length) result[k] = await fn(x[k], k++, x);
    })
  );
  return result;
};

const demo = async () => {
    const wait = (x: number) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, x, x))
    console.time('a')
    console.log(await fastQueue([1000, 2000, 3000, 2000, 2000], 4, (v) => wait(v)))
    console.timeEnd('a')
}
demo();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fast and simple Queue to run multiple parallel task

```js
const defer = () => {
  let resolve;
  let reject;
  const promise = new Promise((_resolve, _reject) => {
    resolve = _resolve;
    reject = _reject;
  });
  return { resolve, reject, promise };
};
 
const lazyFastQueue = (threads, fn, onFree) => {
  const queue = [];
  let ix = 0;
  let count = 0;
  let busy = 0;
  const fun = async () => {
    while (ix < queue.length) {
      const item = queue[ix];
      queue[ix] = undefined;
      ix += 1;
      try {
        item.d.resolve(await fn(item.v, count++));
      } catch (error) {
        item.d.reject(error);
      }
    }
    busy -= 1;
    if (busy === 0) {
      queue.length = 0;
      ix = 0;
      onFree?.();
    }
  };
  return (v) => {
    const d = defer();
    queue.push({ v, d });
    if (busy < threads) {
      busy += 1;
      fun();
    }
    return d.promise;
  };
};

// -----  demo  -----

const wait = (m) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, m, m));

const addTask = lazyFastQueue(3, async (v, i) => {
  console.log('start task', v, i);
  await wait(2000);
  console.log('end task', v, i);
  return i;
});

const fun = () => {
  return Promise.all([
    addTask(1),
    addTask(2),
    addTask(3),
    addTask(4),
    addTask(5),
  ]);
};

fun().then(() => console.log('all done'));
```

## [For Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIRtKEAmAeAFQD5kBvAKGWWwGcB7AGwDcIAuZACibgYFc3kBZAB9kABSh0AtsBoQAMsADWEQkQCUyALwkmdYDgDclahABWEBGHYdsceiHa8QSkHQDuITTuR6DxqgAHSRk5dglpWVViYwBfcnIEOhAaMGQcDGhtZEJsvxwiDnV2dEwobHxibRIKKgYINNpGFgBCG24+ASFRCNCFZWiNat99IxN6xvNLMDbOOwcnFzdPb11RgOQklLTgyLlskAh3cRCotQ4OAH0m5ggAGmRrqatVshMqG5Zsp-pbjY-nmktI9sBYrBtYuoNtgwLwoCAyKZfiwHqDpg9dn1kLE4sZEslUsgGHAAF4ATwAYvYwABFfj8bKEB40vKjQomMAACzsOBo7BAvCkACNoHcTDBHJwmOwCA9gPzBSKoK9emcaUQxVRkhTsBAAPw2V75civWqbAlpACO9IEpF8MsM6RKmXKuDw6uxAG0ALrZH0bCbIYAAD2yAAYAw1zc4gcgI+Mo0LeDQyeGNltCTBnNl7GSQAhOKb3sh3JzgPVOCGcshrRB+AA6eogADmXM0ZqoVAzaWAkCk2Vr-E9Ie9-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-6ABYEZBmH-oAVjR70gJE8h7KKesuWYi5Xl2+p9rGj70mSCBRtKoA)